# C# XML string interpolation

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

When importing a string from XML,
I want to interpolate variables.
What should I do?

```
string name = "X";
string str = "name = {name}";
Debug.Log($str); //<-- I FAILED..
```

Comment: Not possible this way. String interpolation is compiler magic and gets transformed to string.Format in the compiled code. I would go for Regex.Replace (or string.Replace).

Comment: Could you please clarify why the fact you got strings from XML is important and also what exactly does not work when you simply use string interpolation normally `string str=$"name={name}"` ?

Comment: Take a look at the `FormattableString` class, it might help you do what you want:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring?view=netframework-4.7.2. And, what does your question have to do with XML?

Comment: I would advice to look into the xml document reader: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442917/using-xmldocument-to-read-xml

Comment: you forget to use $ as string str = $"name = {name}"; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Answer (score 1):

You forget to use $ - string interpolation.

```
string name = "X";
string str = $"name = {name}";
Debug.Log(str); //<-- You succeed.
```

Comment: if you are using c# console then System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(1, "", str); should be there in place of last line